# Error: TypeError: window.attachEvent is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `custome.js`,`PIE.js` and `jquery1_7_2.js` file in my `jsp`

This is my **custome.js** and nothing more.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(function() {

    if (window.PIE) {
        jQuery('#login-box, .sign-button, .new-user-btn, .grey-btn, .code-btn, #contact-email, #contact-email .continue, #contact-email .cancel').each(function() {
            PIE.attach(this);
        });
    }

});

})
```

everything working fine in all browser. But in Firefox it is showing me this error

```
Error: TypeError: PIE.attach is not a function
Source File: http://localhost:8080/MyApp/js/custom.js
Line: 6
```

Please guide me to solve this issue.

**Edited:**
It showing me error in this line of **PIE.js**

> window.attachEvent("onunload",a);f.K.sa=function(b,c,d){b.attachEvent(c,d);this.ba(function(){b.detachEvent(c,d)})}})();f.Qa=new
>   f.ea;f.K.sa(window,"onresize",function(){f.Qa.wa()});(function(){function
>   a(){f.mb.wa()}f.mb=new
>   f.ea;f.K.sa(window,"onscroll",a);f.Qa.ba(a)})();(function(){function
>   a(){c=f.kb.md()}function b(){if(c){for(var
>   d=0,e=c.length;d

and **custome.js** in this line

> PIE.attach(this);

Comment: is PIE.js an external library?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, No, I have PIE.js in my application folder in same place where custom.js is.

Comment: Yes, but is it an external library? Where did you get it from?

Comment: Yes it is an external library. I don't know from where the UI team get it, But I know that they are downloaded it from the google.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When attaching events in order to make it cross browser perform the following:

```
if (target.addEventListener) {
    target.addEventListener(eventName, handlerName, false);
} else if (target.attachEvent) {
    target.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handlerName);
} else {
    target["on" + eventName] = handlerName;
}
```

Comment: You mean, I have to change my custom.js? as you mentioned in answer or this is something else.

Comment: @subodh I have no idea what PIE is and it provides some definition for attach(). This is to attach event handlers isn't it? If yes then you would probably have to do the change inside the attach.

Comment: Thanks, Konstantin-d-infragistics. I have one more js called PIE.js, It seems custome.js is related to PIE.js

Comment: @subodh Apparently PIE.js assumes that attachEvent is defined for every browser, which is not the case. Whoever is providing you with this js needs to fix it.

Comment: Thanks a million for your effort. Monday I'll ask for this from the team who gives me this JS.